# how to crate cronjo not depending on user access

Tags: wp-cron

i want to use wordpress cron job but it depending on user or admin entering the site, can i override this and make independnt cron on wordpress?

now i use a simple timer when admin enter the admin panel

```
 if ( $nextUpdate <  current_time('timestamp') ){
```

etc..

```
// check if first time update
if ( ($options['lastUpdate'] == 0 ) ){ 
        $today = getdate(current_time('timestamp')); 
        $first_day = getdate(mktime(0,0,0,$today['mon'],1,$today['year'])); 
        $nextUpdate = $first_day[0];
    }
```

etc..

```
$new_settings = array(
    'updatestatus' => $updatestatus,
    'lastUpdate' =>  $nextUpdate,
```

Comment: The WordPress cron jobs needs that WordPress runs, that is because it is needed that someone visit the site. If you need a cron job independent from WordPress you have to create in the server. Ask to your hosting provider.

Comment: thank u for ur answer i know that , but i remmeber that i saw a solution to overcome this problem, and do a trick like user cam in the site so the cron will work.

Answer (score -1):

Have tried plugins for wordpress [cronjob plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/cronjob>)

Cronjob Scheduler and SetCron are worthy a shot...

```
my personal favorite is Cronjob Scheduler..
```

with cronjob scheduler

```
Running your cron tasks
Most shared providers offer a crontab manager, or you can speak to your shared
hosting provider about setting up our cron job. If you manage the server, you 
can setup your cron using the crontab service. Make sure that wget is 
installed befor doing this.

Creating Custom Action Example
function my_cronjob_action () {
   // code to execute on cron run
} add_action('my_cronjob_action', 'my_cronjob_action');
```

[courtesy wordpress plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cronjob-scheduler/installation/#plugin-info)

regds..